# Network is unreachable on rpi-update

Tags: raspbian

I have been following the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) tutorial for my firmware update since i got errors in using picamera module for video recording, and a little search around suggested updating the firmware. Guide me through with it.

```
sudo wget https://raw.github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update/master/rpi-update -O /usr/bin/rpi-update && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/rpi-update
--2014-03-02 14:15:23--  https://raw.github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update/master/rpi-update
Resolving raw.github.com (raw.github.com)... 103.245.222.133
Connecting to raw.github.com (raw.github.com)|103.245.222.133|:443... failed: 
Network is unreachable.
```

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: What is your output of ifconfig
?

Comment: yes i am connected to the internet. i suppose i needed to edit the /root/.bashrc file too for adding proxies if any, because that seemed to solve it.

Comment: i was able to wget google.com and all but when i had to use https, i had problem going on). on a different note, i suppose i needed to edit the /root/.bashrc file too for adding proxies if any, because that seemed to have solve it for now.